# OpenCL how to copy global to global memory

Tags: opencl

I have some complicated algorithm that requires sometimes to copy memory from 1 global buffer to another. Does OpnenCL have any API for that ? Or what is the fastest way to copy data ?
Buffer size may be differed, from 4 bytes to 100Mb.

Comment: There is clEnqueueCopyBuffer on the host.

Comment: You can also do it with a kernel, which will run at full device bandwidth.

Comment: @Dithermaster how to do it ? Just copy word by word ? Is it really fast ?

Comment: The simplest way to to run a 1D kernel where each work item copies one element of data, but the fastest way is to read enough data per work-item to get coalesced reads, typically 128 bits per work-item. So even if your data is bytes, you can read them into a uint4 and write them from the same and you should get full device bandwidth.